# Different format for same Android contact phone number

Tags: java, android

So let's say the SMS conversation is like this:

1. hey nice to meet you (sent by me)
2. yea nice to meet you too (received)
3. let's hang out sometime (replied by me)

The numbers associated with the other person look like this (by checking msg details):

1. 4161234567
2. +14161234567
3. +14161234567

The number stored in my contact's info is (1). How would I access all SMS between myself and this contact all at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by retrieving the thread_id instead, which removes this issue of slightly different phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound crude, but I'd adwise to change to the format in which you receive the text. Reasoning behind it is ,that if you go abroad and need to text this person, there will be a problem, since there will be no country data to go along with this number.

If you want to do this programmatically, I would suggest a regexp, that checks the length of the number, and whether or not there is a country code in front of it. If no, check the contacts to see if there is a number like this with the country code, and use that instead.